# How do I read the names of all the images in the gallery?

Tags: xamarin.android, gallery

I read these links:
`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/content-providers/contacts-contentprovider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839832/mono-android-read-contact-and-number-in-listview`
But I want to read  the names of all the images in the gallery and to save these in a combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access `ContentResolver` directly to get a cursor against a `ContentProvider`.

```
List<string> imageNames = new List<string>();
var imagecursor = ContentResolver.Query(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, null, null,null, null);
//imagecursor.MoveToFirst();
if (imagecursor == null || imagecursor.Count <= 0) return;
while (imagecursor.MoveToNext())
    {
       string name = imagecursor.GetString(imagecursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Title));
       imageNames.Add(name);
    }
imagecursor.Close();
```

Don't forget to ask for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: Hello. I have 3 images in Pictures folder  (test.png and test1.png and test2.png) and use this `Toast.MakeText(this, imageNames.Count.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();` but the result is 0, why?

Comment: Did you ask for the runtime permission ？

Comment: WRIGHT_CONTACTS had been checked before. I removed this tick and my problem was solved. Thank you very much.